# Scraping data with multiple values with same class using python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

hope all are doing well.

In the below program I can get output for product_title and product_header if I use with FOR and findAll I am getting error otherwise I am getting the first value from that website.

For product_tableheader and product_tablevalues I am getting No Tag Found. I tried a lot to find a solution to this. Please help me guys.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class ProductTracker:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}
        self.responce = requests.get(url=self.url, headers= self.user_agent).text
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.responce, 'lxml')

    def product_title(self):
            title = self.soup.find('h1', {'class': 'view-header__primary-heading'})
            if title is not None:
                return title.text
            return "Tag Not Found"

    def product_header(self):
       # for tabletitle in self.soup.findAll('h3', attrs={'class': 'search-table-view__heading'}).text:
            tabletitle = self.soup.find('h3', {'class': 'search-table-view__heading'})
            if tabletitle is not None:
             return tabletitle.text
             return "Tag Not Found"
    def product_tableheader(self):
        tableheader = self.soup.find('span', {'class': 'search-table-view__cell-title'})
        if tableheader is not None:
            return tableheader.text
        return "Tag Not Found"

def product_tablevalues(self):
    tablevalues = self.soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("search-table-view__web-parent-table-row"))
    values_lst = []
    for tablevalue in tablevalues:
        try:
            values_lst.append(tablevalue.td.text.strip())
        except:
                pass
        return values_lst
        return "Tag Not Found"

material = ProductTracker(url = "https://www.grainger.com/category/power-transmission/bearings/ball-bearings/radial-ball-bearings")
print(material.product_title())
print(material.product_header())
print(material.product_tableheader())
print(material.product_tablevalues())
```

Comment: FYI scrapping != scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_all` instead of `findAll` to find all the headings. Here is an example with `product_headers`:

```
    def product_header(self):
       # for tabletitle in self.soup.findAll('h3', attrs={'class': 'search-table-view__heading'}).text:
            tabletitles = self.soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'search-table-view__heading'})
            table_titles_list = []
            for title in tabletitles:
                table_titles_list.append(title.text)
            return table_titles_list
            return "Tag Not Found"
```

Output for the headers:

```
['NTN Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'BL Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'BL Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'DAYTON Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'SKF Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'DAYTON Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'DAYTON Single Row Flanged Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'NTN Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'TIMKEN Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'DAYTON Single Row Flanged Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'MRC Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'SKF Double Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'SKF Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'MRC Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'FAG BEARINGS Double Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'SNR Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'RBC Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'FAG BEARINGS Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'TORRINGTON BEARINGS Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series']
```

The tables in the page are loaded dynamically, so you have to use `selenium` in order to capture details from the tables. Here is how you do it:

Change your `__init__` function to this:

```
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}
        #self.responce = requests.get(url=self.url, headers= self.user_agent).text
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.responce = driver.page_source
        driver.close()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.responce, 'lxml')
```

Change your `product_tableheader` function to this:

```
    def product_tableheader(self):
        tableheaders = self.soup.find_all('th', class_ =  lambda value: value and value.startswith("search-table-view__cell"))
        header_lst = []
        for tableheader in tableheaders:
            try:
                header_lst.append(tableheader.div.a.span.text.strip())
            except:
                try:
                    header_lst.append(tableheader.div.text.strip())
                except:
                    pass 
        return header_lst
        return "Tag Not Found"
```

Output:

```
['Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price', 'Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price', 'Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price', 'Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price']
```

You can extract the table values in a similar way just by modifying the tags to search for and the list names. Happy coding!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223384/discussion-on-answer-by-sushil-scrapping-data-with-multiple-values-with-same-cla).

Comment: @Sushil are you there